# C# Fill dataGridView1 CELL from different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I'm trying to invoke my dataGridView1 from another thread but running into errors, How do I fix it?

Thank you

```
public void SenddataGridView1(int row, int col, string text)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback h = new SetTextCallback(SenddataGridView1);
        this.Invoke(h, new object[] { row, col, text });
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value = text;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"running into errors"*. If only there was a way for us to know what those errors were.

Comment: Thank you for your message. Error line "SetTextCallback h = new SetTextCallback(SenddataGridView1);" and error is "No overload for 'SenddataGridView1" mathes delegate 'Form1.SetTextCallback'"

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is. Your method signature and your delegate signature don't match. Either declare a delegate with a signature that matches your method or, preferably, don't declare your own delegate at all. Just use the inbuilt `Action` and `Func` delegates for void and non-void methods respectively. They can each handle up to 16 parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I just tested this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    SetCellValue(0, 0, "Hello World");
}

public void SetCellValue(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, object value)
{
    if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        dataGridView1.Invoke(new Action<int, int, object>(SetCellValue), columnIndex, rowIndex, value);
    }
    else
    {
        dataGridView1[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value = value;
    }
}
```

and it worked without issue. I don't see a specific issue with your code - I don't know what I'm looking for though - but I can guarantee that this code works.

EDIT: To address the specific issue you were having, which was clear after you provided all the relevant information, you would need to declare your delegate like so:

```
public delegate void SetTextCallback(int row, int col, string text);
```

You just copy the method declaration, change the name and add the delegate keyword.

Comment: Updated to address your specific issue, but you should still stick with `Action` and `Func` delegates.